# Can Someone Identify This Serif Font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

I'm trying to figure out what this font is. It looks similar to Cormorant and Adobe Jenson, but it's not quite it. I've attached the example. Thank you! I really appreciate it! [image]

Comment: It looks nothing like Adobe Jenson, and even less like Cormorant. It looks much more like ITC Tiffany to me, but if you try some of the links given in [this FAQ post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions) about font identification questions, I’m sure you can find an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

It's ITC Tiffany.

It's not my favorite design because of the tilted e and very sharp serifs. If you wanted something similar but a little less 70s maybe try Stormtype Baskerville, Monotype Old Style or Canada Type Ronaldson.

Comment: Thank you so much! ❤️